# Can back to previous page without reload page by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can back to previous page without reload page by JavaScript?

I have 2 HTML pages:

Page 1 after open will click button `Search` data and button `Next` go to Page 2.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function next(){
          window.location.href = "page2.html";
        }
        function create(){
          $("#data").html('<input type="checkbox"/>');
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="create(); return false;" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="next(); return false;" />  

</body>
</html >
```

Page 2 click Back button to go to Page 1.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test2(){
          window.history.back();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="test2(); return false;" />  

</body>
</html >
```

I want to keep status Data in Page 1 when back from Page 2:

I am using `window.history.back()`

```
 $('#btnBack').click(function () {
     window.history.back();            
 });
```

But result of this function is different in each browser:

Chrome, Edge, IE: Page 1 will reload.

FireFox: Page 1 not reload.

Can I process [Chrome, Edge, IE] the same with FireFox?

Comment: I think its browser behavior to cache the previous page, and cannot be set manually

Comment: Can you use window.location.href = "Your back url ";

Comment: It will reload page .

Comment: You should not rely on this behaviour. If you want to keep state between reloads use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
    <button onclick="goBack2()">Go Back2</button>

    <script>
    function goBack() {
      window.history.back();
    }
    function goBack2() {
      window.history.go(-1);
    }
 
    </script>
```

Comment: This is my code. It only working on Firefox, not working on [Chrome, Edge, IE]

Comment: window.history.go(); supported all browsers

Comment: i checked: window.history.go(-1); the same  window.history.back();